# Solving BOM with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, css, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Hello I have designed a header for my website in Html. It works fine.I was having a BOM related issue in PHP which was solved using UTF-8 format hence I can include the header in any of my pages. ï»¿ set has now disappeared but an empty white horizontal gap still exists above my header.How should i get rid of that ?

code for header.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="css/ssHeadFoot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="style1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdTop">&nbsp;
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdMenu" align="center">
                <ul class="ulMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.asp">About Us</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plywood</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fabrication</a></li>                        
                            <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                    <li><a href="Contact us.asp">Contact Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="feedback.asp">Feedback</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.asp">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sign.asp">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

code for demo.php where header.php is included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/ssHeadFoot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually removed the BOM? What do you see when you inspect the elements in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: tried adding UTF-8 to charset.Is there there something I am am missing ?

Comment: The BOM should be removed.

Comment: Are you sure, that this is not a css issue?

Comment: I am using Dream weaver I tried doing: Open your document
Open the Modify menu
Choose Page Properties
Select the Title/Encoding submenu
Select the Encoding dropdown and choose Unicode (UTF-8)
Make sure the checkbox "Include Unicode Signature (BOM)" is unchecked.Still no use .Any advice.

Comment: As I said header alone is running fine so I think its not a CSS issue.

Comment: Instead of thinking you should be inspecting the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this may work
header.php page will be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/ssHeadFoot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- the other code for this page -->
```

and the main page will be

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

some times it's work with me when do this

and try use require_once for the page so when the header.php is missing the code stop and if you include it again no error appear or page require twice

Comment: this when split the main page code to header or when use <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: and the two pages should be without BOM

Comment: Yep I have added <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> tag for both pages.

Comment: what program U use to write the codes ??
because some programs like notepad when select utf-8 it's saved as utf-8 with BOM because this is the default i suffer alot from this

Comment: In Dreamweaver tried: Open your document Open the Modify menu Choose Page Properties Select the Title/Encoding submenu Select the Encoding dropdown and choose Unicode (UTF-8) Make sure the checkbox "Include Unicode Signature (BOM)" is unchecked for both pages.It worked.Thanks